# DIH Indexing is not updating the documents after atomice updates

Tags: solr

I am using Solr 8.0.0, Indexing using DIH is working properly for first time.

**DIH Request Format:**

**Url:**
http://localhost:8983/solr/LatestDemo1/dataimport?command=full-import&Person=1,2,3&entity=Person&commit=true&clean=false

**Indexing data After DIH:**

```
response":{"numFound":2,"start":0,"docs":[
  {
    "id":"P1",
    "Name":"Tom",
    "LastName":"Albert",
    "Gender":"M",
    "Age":"25"
  },
  {
    "id":"P2",
    "Name":"Jack",
    "LastName":"Albert",
    "Gender":"M",
    "Age":"20"
  },
]}
```

**Update Using Atomic Updates Using Solr API**

Url: http://localhost:8983/solr/LatestDemo1/update?commit=true

Method:Post

Data:

```
[
    {
     "id":"P1",
     "Age":{"set":"25"}
    },
    {
     "id":"P1",
     "Age":{"set":"20"}
    },
]
```

**Indexing data after Atomic Updates:**

```
response":{"numFound":2,"start":0,"docs":[
  {
    "id":"P1",
    "Name":"Tom",
    "LastName":"Albert",
    "Gender":"M",
    "Age":"25"
  },
  {
    "id":"P2",
    "Name":"Jack",
    "LastName":"Albert",
    "Gender":"M",
    "Age":"20"
  },
]}
```

So After performing Indexing using DIH again, it will remove the record of Age Field which was updated by atomic update & document looks like as below:

```
response":{"numFound":2,"start":0,"docs":[
  {
    "id":"P1",
    "Name":"Tom",
    "LastName":"Albert",
    "Gender":"M"
  },
  {
    "id":"P2",
    "Name":"Jack",
    "LastName":"Albert",
    "Gender":"M"
  },
]}
```

So After doing the indexing using DIH should not remove my Age Field which was updated by Atomic update

Any suggestions are appreciated..Thanks in advance.

Comment: in the in atomic update request why are you using clean=true?

Comment: Thank you for response, sorry by mistake i have set clean=true in atomic update but actually i am not using  clean parameter so let me remove this..Thank you

Comment: is it possible to share the schema.xml ?

Comment: Why is there no `id` field after your second update, and is really the `age` field present after the initial import? Your atomic update is effectively setting the same value twice for the same document if your included requests are real.

Comment: Please check @MatsLindh, its coming,i forgot to add 'id' in last update

Comment: so in the second DIH, Age field is getting removed...then does the source from where the data is been fetched by DIH has the data with the age field?

Comment: could you confirm your second DIH command? is it full-import? if yes, you should use delta-import as your command and clean=false....It work perfectly at my end...